# How to get server details of a member

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How to get details of a member using his UserID. like example i want to know in which server(name and ID) he is member of were ever my bot is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as looping through all of the servers the bot has access to and trying to retrieve the `Member` object from each server for that ID.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def getUser(ctx, id):
    # id = int(id)  #  On the rewrite branch, ids are ints
    for server in bot.servers:
        member = server.get_member(id)
        if member:
            await bot.say(f"Server Name: {server.name}")
            await bot.say(f"Server ID:   {server.id}")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```